# SyntaxError in python script that creates a qiime2 manifest file

Tags: python, manifest, fastq, qiime

My script creates a manifest document that contains the filepaths of my fastq data for upload into qiime2. The input is a text file of the sample names and a directory that contains the fastq files. I then run the shell file using `python ./manifest_single.py --input-dir seqs`. Input text file example:

> SRR123456 SRR123457 SRR123458...

Below is my shell file

```
#!/local/cluster/bin/python3

# assign a variable to the file of interest
file_name = "seq.by.sys_accession.txt"
dir = "/filepath/seqs"

# open the file with a file handle
read_SRR = open(file_name, "r")

# obtain a list of lines in your file
allLines_list = read_SRR.readlines()

# create output file
outFile = "manifest.txt"

read_outFile = open(outFile, "w")
read_outFile.write(f"sample-id\tabsolute-filepath\n")

# loop over the body of data lines until the end of the file
for rawLine in allLines_list:
    line = rawLine.strip()
    print(f"|{line}|")
    with open(outFile, "a") as f:
        read_outFile.write(f"{line}\t{dir}/{line}.R1.fastq.gz\n")

outFile.close()
read_SRR.close()
```

But I keep receiving the error

```
[name@congo metagenome-analysis]$ python ./manifest_single.py --input-dir seqs
  File "./manifest_single.py", line 17
    read_outFile.write(f"sample-id\tabsolute-filepath\n")
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've changed the `\t` and `\n` with a literal "tab". I've triple checked my input file structure and contents.

Comment: What is the output of executing `python --version`?

Comment: That was it. I used `python3` instead and that worked. I need more coffee